# How to clear out a file input event in Angular / Typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, events

I'm building an image upload portal that opens a modal and allows the user to drag and drop image files into the upload div.  That is working and the images get processed however I've run into an issue where when I open the modal again for a different item and try to upload a different image, when I drag it in, suddenly all the other images I've uploaded before appear even though I've cleared the array of objects populating it and tried clearing the event.

I've put "stopImmediatePropogation()" at the end of my host listeners

```
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
  
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.dataTransfer) {
      this.handleFiles(event.dataTransfer.files);
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
```

I've tried several of the various methods below to clear the event / file input after they have been processed

```
  onFileInputChange(event: Event) {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.handleFiles(inputElement.files);

    //inputElement.type = 'text';
    //inputElement.value = ''; 
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('cleared');  //this never executes
  }
```

When closing the modal and opening a new one, I clear out all the structures interacting with and populating it

```
  uploadImage(vehicle: Vehicle): void {
    this.uploadVehicle = vehicle;
    this.linkedListArray.length = 0;
    this.imageList.length = 0;
    this.showModal = true;
  }
```

EDIT: Here's the front end code:

```
<div class="file-upload upload-modal" *ngIf="showModal">

  <h3>Upload images for {{ uploadVehicle.Year }} {{ uploadVehicle.Make }} {{ uploadVehicle.Model }}</h3>

    <div
      class="drop-zone"
      (drop)="onDrop($event)"
      (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
    >
      <p>Drag and drop files into the window, or click to select files - then click the <span class="highlight">showcase image</span></p>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="fileInput"
        style="color:transparent; width:120px;"
        multiple
        (change)="onFileInputChange($event)"
      />

      
    </div>

    <div class="file-list" id="file-list">

        <div *ngFor="let image of linkedListArray; let i = index">
          <img (click)="activateClass(image)" [ngClass]="{'active': image.active}" class="uploadedImage" [src]="image.url" alt="{{ image.name }}" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <br>    

    <div class="modal-button-container">
    <button type="button" (click)="closeModal()" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the closeModal function where I try again to clear everything

```
  closeModal(){
    console.log("clicked");
    this.linkedListArray.length = 0;
    this.imageList.length = 0;
    this.showModal = false;
    this.logLists();
  }
```

Also, here's the handleFiles() function.  I've added provisions in here to prevent duplicate image files from going forward although I'm not sure if it's working properly:

```
  private handleFiles(files: FileList | null) {
    if (files) {

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        const file: File = files[i];
        const fileName = file.name;

        console.log(fileName);
        
        // Check if an image with the same name already exists in the array
        const isDuplicate = this.linkedListArray.some(image => image.name == fileName);
        const ext = '.' + fileName.split('.').pop();

        if ( (ext == '.png' || ext == '.jpg' || ext == '.jpeg') && !isDuplicate){
          this.files.push(files[i]);
          const imageObject: ImageObject = {
            id: i,
            name: file.name,
            blob: new Blob([file], { type: file.type }),
            active: false
          };
  
          imageObject.url = URL.createObjectURL(imageObject.blob);
    
          // Add it to the array
          this.imageList.append(imageObject);
          this.linkedListArray = this.linkedListService.linkedListToArray(this.imageList);
        }
      }      
    }
    let FileList = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById("file-list");
    setTimeout(() => FileList.scrollTop = 0, 300); 
    //files = null;
  }
```

Comment: I need your html code to understand all. But I think your problem is the cleaning part. Then you write the part `console.log('cleared');` never execute. So I think you have an error in your `this.handleFiles(inputElement.files);` **OR** the function will be never called.

Comment: I edited the post to include the functions

Comment: I have tested your code (so good as possible) and if you use the `input` and select file with browser the "cleared" will logged in console. If you use drag and drop it cannot be logged because the `onFileInputChange` cannot fire

Comment: Ok, maybe I should just stick with that for now and try something else for the drag and drop.  Thank you!